# Black screen when trying to render multiple textures

Tags: glsl, opengl-es

I generate an array for two textures:

```
int[] textureID = new int[2];
glGenTextures(1, textureID, 0);
glGenTextures(1, textureID, 1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[1]);
```

Render:

```
int Position = glGetAttribLocation(Shader.program_Image, mPosition);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(Position);
glVertexAttribPointer(Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
int TexCoordLoc = glGetAttribLocation(Shader.program_Image, atexCoord );
glEnableVertexAttribArray (TexCoordLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer (TexCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, uvBuffer);
int mtrxBackground = glGetUniformLocation(Shader.program_Image, mbackground);
int mtxObj = glGetUniformLocation(Shader.program_Image, mobj);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxBackground, 1, false, m, 0);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mtxObj, 1, false, m, 0);
int mSamplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation (Shader.program_Image, bTexture);
int mSamplerLoc1 = glGetUniformLocation (Shader.program_Image, sTexture);
glUniform1i (mSamplerLoc, 0);
glUniform1i(mSamplerLoc1, 1);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, background.getIndices().length, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

My fragment shader is like this.

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D b_texture;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(b_texture, v_texCoord );
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord ); 
}
```

I have no error message, but when I run the application, I only see a black screen.

The app runs correctly with just one texture, but doesn't with more than one. What's wrong in my code?

Do I have to add another set of coordinates and update the vertex shader? Because I have only one “rectangle” constructed from two triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequentially binding two textures without doing anything in the middle is pointless. Only one texture is bound at a time, so in this case it's the last one.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[1]);
```

Also, a fragment shader only has one output, if you override it, only the last will count. If you want to mix the textures, you have to decide how to do it, do you want them to be multiplicative, additive? Do you want them to just blend by the alpha?

```
vec4 col1 = texture2D(b_texture, v_texCoord );

vec4 col2 = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord );
gl_FragColor = col1 + col2;
//gl_FragColor = col1 * col2;
//gl_FragColor = vec4(col1.rgb * (1.0f - col2.a) + col2.rgb * col2.a, 1.0f);
```